# Java Trying to write to files, with the names of the files being stored in an array. The files are being created when I run it, but nothing is in them

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

I have included skeleton code below. I'm sure it's just something simple, but I have no idea how to debug the printwriter and filewriter.

```
String[] outputs = {"output_1.txt", "output_2.txt"};
PrintWriter writer = null;
FileWriter file = null;

for(int i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++){

    file = new FileWriter(outputs[i]);
    writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    writer.println("write this to file");

}
```

Comment: You need to close the stream (the `Writer`) when finished. Use try-with-resources

Comment: Or you can directly call `writer.flush()` if you need to write to a file before you close the stream for some reason. (This is what is called when you close a stream so you don't need to manually call it if you just want stuff written when closed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PrintWriter failing to print to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689269/printwriter-failing-to-print-to-file)

Comment: thank you all! writer.close() at the end of the loop solved it!

Comment: @eric_on_strike While that works, you definitely want to use [try-with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which will automatically close it for you.

Comment: `try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputPath)))) { // loop code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to close the file when you are done writing to it. You can do that with `writer.close()`, however, this is not ideal for multiple reasons:

- If something goes wrong while writing to the file (i.e. an exception is thrown) the function will exit prematurely and writer.close() will never be called. While this doesn't matter in this particular example, this can leave so-called dead-locks in bigger programs, which is never a good idea.
- People are lazy and you will more often than not forget to call `writer.close()` the next time you have a similar task.

Therefore, start making good habits now and use the following:

```java
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputs[i])))) {
    writer.println("write this to file");
}
```

Under the hood, this does the following for you:

```java
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputs[i])))
try {
    writer.println("write this to file");
} finally {
    writer.close()
}
```

which has the following advantages:

- Because the call to `close()` is in the `finally` block, `close()` will be called after successfully writing to the file but also if anything goes wrong.
- The `close()` call is added for you implicitly so you have one thing less to think about.